# How to clean the value of a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

In **PostgreSQL** database with 2 table which called `sections` and `options`. Inside the `option` table I have foreign key column called `next_section`.

**SECTIONS**:

```
| ID | NAME   |
|----|--------|
| 15 | Kolesa |
| 16 | Market |
```

**OPTIONS**:

```
| ID | TEXT | NEXT_SECTION |
|----|------|--------------|
| 1  | YES  | 15           |
| 2  | NO   | 16           |
```

I created that colomn with next sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE OPTIONS 
ADD COLUMN NEXT_SECTION INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (NEXT_SECTION) 
REFERENCES SECTIONS (ID);
```

When I delete some record from section table I need to clear the value inside `next_section` colomn of option table. How to modify that column?

Comment: did you try **ON DELETE SET NULL / SET CASCADE **

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I found the solution:

```
ALTER TABLE OPTIONS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (NEXT_SECTION)
REFERENCES SECTIONS (ID)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```